# Symfony 2 Guard component and a normal login form

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use the new [Guard](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-guard-authentication-component) component. The only information I found about it are the [official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html).

The example from the docs uses Guard to authenticate API's requests.

According to the docs it can be also used with a normal login form, what I want to do.

I copied that example and replaced two functions:

```
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return array(
        'username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
        'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
    );
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $email = $credentials['username'];

    $user = $this->em->getRepository('Entity\User')
        ->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));

    return $user;
}
```

security.yml:

```
providers:
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: Entity\User
            property: email

firewalls:
    user:
        switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        pattern:  ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: user_provider
        form_login:
            check_path: login_check
            login_path: login
        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: login
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.ldap.authenticator
        stateless: false
```

The problem is that Symfony doesn't persist my session.

I'm logged in only if I send data form for every request. Is it possible to send this data once just like a normal login form?

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I had in security.yml

```
always_authenticate_before_granting:  true
```

copied from another project :). I deleted it and now it works